# Is Unity endian-ness platform independent?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I was just wondering if I can reliably expect C# code to be little endian in Unity.

I'm using an int as a bitmap to determine the state of a room where there are four statues.  Each statue can have its arms up or down.  I use 8 bits to represent the arms.  1 == up 0 == down.

```
        int bit = (int)statueNumber * 2;
        if (!isLeftArm) bit += 1;
        bool up = (1 == ((roomState >> bit) & 1));
```

This tells me if an arm is up or down.  Eventually I compare "roomState" to another integer represented the "correct" room state.  Let's say the correct state is 1010101, then the answer is 85 in little endian.  But if it's interpreted as big endian it's another number.

Comment: Is there any purpose for saving a few bytes by not using plain booleans, when the whole engine + C# runtime take hundreds of megabytes to run? Premature optimizations?

Comment: Maybe not.  I was actually trying to avoid bloating the namespace of my game state map.  It's the difference of 8 keys vs 1.

But maybe it's not worth it.

Comment: Ok, so encoding 8 keys in 1 byte per statue is reasonable. But why bother to use `int` then? Maybe `byte[]`?

Comment: So I'm using a save system (Dialogue System for Unity) that only supports certain data types.  byte[] isn't among them sadly.

Comment: Well, but `byte` should be supported, so following a dirty way you can store a separate byte per statue, though it's not really scalable coding-wise

Comment: Actually, I can just use a string!  I'll do that.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: If you only need a byte and only use a byte, your concern for endians disappears